# How to shield a DB?

Tags: java, database, api, architecture, data-access-layer

I have to provide an access to my semantics. Currently, it is an RDBMS but later I'll probably use additional non-RDBMS data sources (graph, hadoop etc).

The consumers of my semantics are located inside company domain/intranet but run on remote servers. Moreover, as we are in design stage, it is unclear what technology they will use for implementing their business logic (Java/C or other).
I think it would be a bad idea to provide to external modules of our SW a direct access to my Data Model over JDBC/ODBC (because i do not want to be committed to RDBMS only).

The plan is to create an API to access my semantics. The API is basically, CRUD. Current candidate is REST API using Spring.

My concern is that the access over REST might be slow.
Preferably the technology would be Java-based. However, C-base and others are welcome as well.

I wonder: what alternatives to REST shall I consider?
The only requirement except for the speed of access is that it must be easy to implement and maintain.

I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just internal calls behind company firewall, RMI would allow to create arbitrary complex API with multiple methods that accept and return complex data structures. CORBA will also do. These technologies are part of JavaSE.

From the newer technologies, [Google protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) may not be bad for this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shield your domain model from your data model, you can just put a layer of abstraction in between, i.e. interfaces. Why do you think you need a remoting boundary? Providing a remotely accessible API over REST is completely orthogonal to your concern of eliminating coupling between your domain and data model.

The consumers of your API will always be shielded from your private domain model anyway. If you're building a java API you'll expose interfaces and with a remote and orthogonal REST interface, you'll be exposing HTTP resources.

Comment: It might be not clear in the question but my semantics need to be accessed remotely. Hence, "...Providing a remotely accessible API over REST is completely orthogonal to your concern ..." is not accurate. Do you have any specific suggestion or just a general statement about "just put a layer of abstraction..." which does not contribute much (IMO)?

Comment: I would suggest forming the question more clearly and in greater detail if you want a specific answer. What is the API's purpose? Who are its consumers? For example, if the API needs to cater to varying types of clients, I would choose REST. If all clients are Java, and I'm willing to lock myself in and deal with the pain of re bundling binaries for clients when I change the API, I could opt for Java RMI. These choices are contextual and must be taken carefully. I gave a general suggestion to nudge you in the right direction and get you thinking about the problem.

Comment: i edited my question to emphasise the fact that my semantics need to be accessed remotely and the API is CRUD. I believe that now you can be more specific in your answer as well.